# Creating Timestamp column with ormlite

Tags: android, mysql, ormlite

I have a column like this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.TIME_STAMP)
Timestamp time;
```

When I create the DAO I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class class java.sql.Timestamp for
    field FieldType:name=time,class=Vote is not valid for data persister
    com.j256.ormlite.field.types.TimeStampType@334ecfe8
```

It's been one day that I'm trying different methods and none is working. Note that I have updated my ormlite jar to 4.41.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date` fields was added in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) version 4.41 but they had an associated bug.  These were fixed in version 4.42.

In the meantime, I think you might be able to fix it by removing the `dataType` specifier.  I think that it should be able to auto-detect the type.  The problem is when you are specifying the data-type.

```
// no dataType specified
@DatabaseField
Timestamp time;
```