# ORMLite issues on MySQL creating Timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp, ormlite

I am having problems creating Timestamps with MySql. Followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957983/creating-timestamp-column-with-ormlite) in terms of not using a specific `DataType.TIME_STAMP` entry in the `@DatabaseField` definition.

My current `@DatabaseField` looks like this:

```
 @DatabaseField(format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 private Timestamp updatedAt;
```

Still getting errors on Table create:

```
Unable to create table because of [Problems parsing default date
string 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS']
```

So it seems to be ignoring the format definition, without the format definition, I still get this error:

```
Unable to create table because of [Problems parsing default date
string 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS']
```

I have tried specifying the dataType, changing it to `DATE_TIME`, etc. I've not yet found a combination (other than not using Timestamp at all and just create a `DATE_TIME`, which works, but not with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).

I'm really stuck, since I've manually updated the tables in the past, but now the number is growing and I'd like to have the processes automated fully using the Create Table options in ORMLite, without having to manually mess with the schema later.

Any pointers would be very welcome on how to get this working.

Comment: There may be a messaging problem Anthony here.  The problem is that `"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` cannot be used as a default value because it doesn't match the conversion pattern.  I guess I need to special case this somehow.  Since each DB type does this differently, this is going to be a pain.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the ultra fast response Gray. I understand the issue, would one way of treating it be let the user figure it out? If you put the MySQL version into Postres the table create will naturally fail. So it is a class design problem, not an infrastructure one, if you see what I mean. Perhaps simply accepting whatever is typed in the defaultValue field ONLY for Timestamps would work? User's responsibility to get it right. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yeah that might be the right solution.  The _perfect_ solution would be to have some sort of Timestamp validator on the abstract database type.  :-)  I'm actually a little surprised that it needs to do string parsing.  I'll look at this later today.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye out for the results. BTW your brain teasers are fun!

Comment: I have downloaded the sources to see if I can make a more constructive suggestion. However, I can't seem to grep the phrase "problems parsing" in any of the sources. Beginning to get a handle on how ORMLite works under the covers. Can't find where the SQL for each field type is generated, since the annotations presumably create a dynamically allocated delegate of DatabaseFieldConfig. Can't find where the SQL code gets "filled" for the method getColumnDefinition()

Comment: Found the parsing message in DateStringType.java and parent classes.

Comment: My suggestion would be to adapt normalizeDateString(...) to ignore the defaultValue "conflict" specifically for Timestamp types only. Not sure if I've got the exact method to implement this, but I think I'm barking up the right tree.

Comment: Gray, any updates on this? I'm currently using 4.44 and appear to have the same issues... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now there doesn't look to be a way to accomplish this except using the `@DatabaseFiled(version = true)` which doesn't work for `Timestamp` fields.  This has been remedied in trunk and will be working in 4.46:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/version-field

To get it to work with Timestamp fields in 4.45 is pretty each though.  You'll need to `extends TimeStampType` and override the following method.  See the bottom of this answer for more details:

```
@Override
public Object moveToNextValue(Object currentValue) {
    long newVal = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentValue == null) {
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(newVal);
    } else if (newVal == ((java.sql.Timestamp) currentValue).getTime()) {
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(newVal + 1L);
    } else {
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(newVal);
    }
}
```

Then specify your field as:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = LocalCurrentTimeStampType.class, version = true)
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;
```

---

[[The following works for the create date but not for other updates.  I'll leave it for general information.]]

This was non-trivial but I finally figured out the way you can do this using the latest version from trunk.  In 4.46 we will be adding support for `@DatabaseField(readOnly = true)` for fields that are only read-only.  This allows you to say:

```
@DatabaseField(defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()", readOnly = true)
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;
```

Read-only fields are never created or updated -- only returned in queries.  The problem is that the `TimeStampType` throws an exception when it tries to validate the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.  To resolve this you need to define a custom persister:

```
public class LocalCurrentTimeStampType extends TimeStampType {
    private static final LocalCurrentTimeStampType singleton =
        new LocalCurrentTimeStampType();
    private String defaultStr;
    public LocalCurrentTimeStampType() {
        super(SqlType.DATE, new Class<?>[] { java.sql.Timestamp.class });
    }
    public static LocalCurrentTimeStampType getSingleton() {
        return singleton;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEscapedDefaultValue() {
        if ("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()".equals(defaultStr)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.isEscapedDefaultValue();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType fieldType, String defaultStr) throws SQLException {
        this.defaultStr = defaultStr;
        if ("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()".equals(defaultStr)) {
            return defaultStr;
        } else {
            return super.parseDefaultString(fieldType, defaultStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your field definition becomes:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = LocalCurrentTimeStampType.class,
    defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()", readOnly = true)
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;
```

You can get the latest version from github code: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core

Comment: Thanks Gray- I understand the technical constraints but at least it saves editing lots of tables.

Comment: I encountered strange behaviour when using ORMlite on self greated tables. If I create a table with a `cdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` column and do not mark it as `@DatabaseField(readOnly = true)` in the object definition, it does not set the default timestamp even if I created the tables directly.  Does ORMlite explicit set null values when executing an insert statement?